# Speed up numpy summation between big arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a code running operations on `numpy` arrays.
While linear algebra operations seem fast, I now am finding a bottleneck in a different issue: the summation of two distinct arrays. 
In the example below `WE3` and `T1` are two `1000X1000X1000` arrays.
First I calculate `WE3` using a numpy operation, then I sum those arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import time
N = 100
n = 1000
X = np.random.uniform(size = (N,n))
wE = np.mean(X,0)
wE3 = np.einsum('i,j,k->ijk', wE, wE, wE) #22 secs
T1 = np.random.uniform(size = (n,n,n))
a = wE3 + T1 #115 secs
```

The calculation of `wE3` takes like 22 seconds, while the addition between `WE3` and `T1` takes 115 seconds.

Is there any known reason why the summation of those arrays is such slower than the calculation of WE3? They should have more or less the same complexity..

Is there a way to speed up that code?

Comment: preallocate a with `a = np.empty_like(T1)`? otherwise you're not likely to get any faster. numpy internally calls `fork()` to run operations in parallel and consists of reasonably well optimized C code.

Comment: @Aaron - Numpy doesn't implement threading. Some functions may use multiple threads, but that completely depends on underlying libraries like BLAS, LAPACK, FFTPACK, etc. Most notably, none of the `ufunc`'s (elementwise operations) are multit-threaded.

Comment: @user6758673 you are correct, I was only aware that it sometimes did fork into multiple threads, but not specifically when.. I would like to point out, however numpy operations do almost always release the GIL to allow use of threading to speed up code instead of multiprocessing..

Answer (score 1):

That `np.einsum('i,j,k->ijk', wE, wE, wE)` part isn't doing any sum-reduction and is essentially just broadcasted elementwise multiplication. So, we can replace that with something like this -

```
wE[:,None,None] * wE[:,None] * wE
```

Runtime test -

```
In [9]: # Setup inputs at 1/5th of original dataset sizes
   ...: N = 20
   ...: n = 200
   ...: X = np.random.uniform(size = (N,n))
   ...: wE = np.mean(X,0)
   ...: 

In [10]: %timeit np.einsum('i,j,k->ijk', wE, wE, wE)
10 loops, best of 3: 45.7 ms per loop

In [11]: %timeit wE[:,None,None] * wE[:,None] * wE
10 loops, best of 3: 26.1 ms per loop
```

---

Next up, we have `wE3 + T1`, where `T1 = np.random.uniform(size = (n,n,n))`  doesn't look like could  be helped in a big way as we have to create `T1` anyway and then it's just element-wise addition. It seems we can use [`np.add`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.add.html) that lets us write back the results to one of the arrays : `wE3` or `T1`. Let's say we choose `T1`, if  that's okay to be modified. I guess this would bring slight memory efficiency as we won't be adding another variable into workspace.

Thus, we could do -

```
np.add(wE3,T1,out=T1)
```

Runtime test -

```
In [58]: def func1(wE3):
    ...:     T1 = np.random.uniform(size = (n,n,n))
    ...:     return wE3 + T1
    ...: 
    ...: def func2(wE3):
    ...:     T1 = np.random.uniform(size = (n,n,n))
    ...:     np.add(wE3,T1,out=T1)
    ...:     return T1
    ...: 

In [59]: # Setup inputs at 1/4th of original dataset sizes
    ...: N = 25
    ...: n = 250
    ...: X = np.random.uniform(size = (N,n))
    ...: wE = np.mean(X,0)
    ...: wE3 = np.einsum('i,j,k->ijk', wE, wE, wE)
    ...: 

In [60]: %timeit func1(wE3)
1 loops, best of 3: 390 ms per loop

In [61]: %timeit func2(wE3)
1 loops, best of 3: 363 ms per loop
```

Using [`@Aaron's suggestion`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39923085/speed-up-numpy-summation-between-big-arrays#comment67131799_39923433), we can use a loop and assuming that writing back the results into `wE3` is okay, we could do -

```
wE3 = wE[:,None,None] * wE[:,None] * wE
for x in wE3: 
    np.add(x, np.random.uniform(size = (n,n)), out=x)
```

**Final results**

Thus, putting back all the suggested improvements, finally the runtime test results were -

```
In [97]: def func1(wE):
    ...:     wE3 = np.einsum('i,j,k->ijk', wE, wE, wE)
    ...:     T1 = np.random.uniform(size = (n,n,n))
    ...:     return wE3 + T1
    ...: 
    ...: def func2(wE):
    ...:     wE3 = wE[:,None,None] * wE[:,None] * wE
    ...:     for x in wE3: 
    ...:         np.add(x, np.random.uniform(size = (n,n)), out=x)
    ...:     return wE3
    ...: 

In [98]: # Setup inputs at 1/3rd of original dataset sizes
    ...: N = 33
    ...: n = 330
    ...: X = np.random.uniform(size = (N,n))
    ...: wE = np.mean(X,0)
    ...: 

In [99]: %timeit func1(wE)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.09 s per loop

In [100]: %timeit func2(wE)
1 loops, best of 3: 879 ms per loop
```

Comment: I tried running it real quick without thinking of the implications first -_- computer crashed: out of memory :P

Comment: @Aaron Yeah same here on my old laptop, that's why the smaller datasets. But since OP was able to run it, so hopefully the runtime figures should be proportional on the actual dataset.

Comment: if `wE3` can be modified (it is only random numbers after all) I'm curious what you'd get with func3: `for x in wE3: np.add(x, np.random.uniform(size = (n,n)), out=x)` I would think the reduced memory pressure of not having to create the full T1 could speed things up as well..

Comment: @Aaron Maybe on larger arrays that could help, I am not sure (can't test out). But that's a good suggestion! OP should take a note of it.

Comment: @Aaron Squeezed bigger dataset and incorporated your idea! Good improvement there I must say. Thank you for suggesting that!

Comment: I also would also use `np.float32` for another half the memory (same execution speed), but `np.float16` was about twice slower for some reason (bad optimization for half precision?)

Comment: @Aaron Yeah I guess we should leave that part to OP, as per their requirements with precision.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125203/discussion-between-aaron-and-divakar).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any known reason why the summation of those arrays is such slower than the calculation of WE3?

The arrays `wE3`, `T1` and `a` each require 8 gigabytes of memory.  You are probably running out of physical memory, and [swap memory](https://serverfault.com/questions/48486/what-is-swap-memory) access is killing your performance.

> Is there a way to speed up that code?

Get more physical memory (i.e. RAM).

If that is not possible, take a look at what you are going to do with these arrays, and see if you can work in batches such that the total memory required when processing a batch remains within the limits of your physical memory.

Answer (score 0):

You should really use Numba's Jit (just in time compiler) for this.  It is a purely numpy pipeline, which is perfect for Numba.

All you have to do is throw that above code into a function, and put an @jit decorater on top.  It gets speedups close to Cython.

However, as others have pointed out, it appears you're trying to work with data too large for your local machine, and numba would not solve your problems